# Java:how to group similar strings (items) to respective array (group)?

Tags: java

I have the following string `"0#Aitem, 0#Aitem2, 0#Aitem3, 1#Bitem, 1#Bitem2, 2#Citem, Nitem, Nitem2".`

the 0# shows group number. so `Aitem, Aitem2, Aitem3` will belong to group `0`. `Bitem, Bitem2` in group `1`. `Citem` in group `2`. If there is no group number, they will all be place in separate group. So `Nitem, Nitem2` will be placed in group `3`.

I would like to create an array for each group, and place the "items" in respective group(array). So I would end up with something like

```
[array("Aitem,Aitem2,Aitem3"), array("Bitem, Bitem2"), array("Citem"), array("Nitem, Nitem2")]
```

I am guessing I need an arrayList to hold all the groups (arrays) which respectively has appropriate elements (items).

This is what I started with but I don't know if this is the best approach. The string is dynamic, so there can be any number of groups and has to follow the criteria above.

```
String[] x = Pattern.compile(",").split("0#item, 0#item2, 0#item3, 1#item, 1#item2, 2#item, item");
   for (int ii=0; ii<x.length; ii++) {
       System.out.println(i + " \"" + x[ii] + "\"");
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer shows how you can use a **single regex** to extract both the group and the item. You can then store these in a map.

```
    String s =  "0#Aitem, 0#Aitem2, 0#Aitem3, 1#Bitem, 1#Bitem2, 2#Citem, Nitem, Nitem2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*)[#]{0,1}(\\w+?)(,|$)");        
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
    while(m.find()){
        String group = m.group(1);
        String item = m.group(2);
        List<String> items = map.get(group);
        if(items == null){
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(group, items);
        }
        items.add(item);
    }
    //let's print it out
    for(String key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
    }
```

prints:

```
 : [Nitem, Nitem2]
0 : [Aitem, Aitem2, Aitem3]
1 : [Bitem, Bitem2]
2 : [Citem]
```

At the moment, items with no group are keyed against an empty string. I'll leave it at as an exercise for you to handle this scenario. It should simply be a case of finding the max key and incrementing it.

I'm sure the regex can be improved too as it was written in haste.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Create a map for storing groups
Map<String, Collection<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();

String[] parts = yourString.split("[, ]+"); //Split by each word
for (String part : parts) {   //Go over all words
    String[] subparts = part.split("#"); //Split to index and value

    String groupKey;
    String value;
    if (subparts.length == 1) { //There is no '#' sign
        groupKey = null;
        value = subparts[0];
    } else if (subparts.length == 2) { //There is one '#'sign
        groupKey = subparts[0];
        value = subparts[1];
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not parse string");
    }

    Collection<String> groupContents = groupMap.get(groupKey); //Extract list of items in this group
    if (groupContents == null) { //If there was no such group yet - create one
        groupMap.put(groupKey, groupContents = new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    groupContents.add(value); //Add item to group
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String,List<String> myItems = new HashMap<String,List<String>);
```

Then you can whatever class you want with an sting alias and store as many items as you whish.

Answer (score 1):

You are on right way but I'd like to correct you a little bit.

Use the following regex to split: `str.split("\\s*,\\s*")`. This will support all possible spaces.

When you get separate item you have to split it again: `item.split("#")`.

To store all this create data structure like `List<List<String>>`. Then do the following:

```
String[] parts = item.split("#");
int group = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
String itemName = parts[1];
List<String> groupList = allGroups.get(group);
if (groupList == null) {
   groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
   allGroups[group] = groupList;
}
groupList.add(itemName);
```

I am sorry if the code sample contains syntax errors. It is written here, on the site and should just help you to see the idea.

Comment: I was thinking about using List<List> too, but it will fail in case of `0#item,5#item`. And is not mentioned by the author that all the indexes are incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on Maps.

```
    System.out.println("###Parsing results and populating map");
    String[] x = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*").split(
            "0#item, 0#item2, 0#item3, 1#item, 1#item2, 2#item, item");

    Map<String, List<String>> result = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        String y[] = x[i].split("#");

        if (y.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("group: '" + y[0] + "' item: '" + y[1] + "'");
            List<String> l = result.get(y[0]);
            if(l==null){
                l = new ArrayList<String>();
                result.put(y[0], l);
            }
            l.add(y[1]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("###Returning values stored in map, as separate arrays");
    for(Entry<String,List<String>> entry: result.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Group:" + entry.getKey());
        //System.out.println("Items:");
        List <String> l = entry.getValue();
        // This is where the final array is
        String[] finalArray = l.toArray(new String[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(finalArray[i]);
        }

    }
```